# Form field not retaining input data

Tags: php, forms, input, field, isset

I can't seem to figure out why when I submit the form, and it returns with the error message, that it doesn't retain what I've entered into the fields.  Here's an example of my input field:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['the_field'])) echo $_POST['the_field'];?>" name="the_field" id="the_field"/>
```

I'm using sessions for my error message handling.  But I don't think that would make a difference, right?  Any ideas?

part of my FORM:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" name="edit" id="edit">
<input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['name']))  echo htmlentities($_POST['name']);  ?>" name="name" id="name" class="text" tabindex="1"/>
<input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['the_field'])) echo $_POST['the_field'];?>" name="the_field" id="the_field"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Create" name="action"/>
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Create New Project" />
</form>
```

part of my PROCESS.PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    switch($_POST['action']){   
        case 'Create':
        $client = $_POST['client'];
            if(empty($_POST['name'])){
              $_SESSION['error'] = 'You need to enter a project name!';
              header('location: add.php');
              exit; 
            }
    }
break;
}
```

Do you think that it's because the NAME field is processed before THE_FIELD and when the NAME errors, it doesn't pass anything back?

Comment: are you making sure you have method='post' for your <form> and you might want to do print_r($_POST); to check the post data.

Comment: There are only 2 reasons I can think of when this won't work. 1. The method to submit the form is different. 2. There is a redirect in the middle somewhere. form.html->formHandler.php->form.html route is taken. The error message will be retained due to sessions, but the value will be lost. So why don't u post the filenames and the complete form so we can help

Comment: You might want to check the view source to check what is being outputted eg:error/php tags etc.

Comment: add your full form structure in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to use sessions since I was posting to a process page, which seemed to be the reason, and not SELF.  Takes a bit more time but does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if `isset`, to show what was sent by `post` you must to write `$_POST['the_field']` like this:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['the_field']);?>" name="the_field" id="the_field"/>
```

**UPDATE**

Don't use `sessions` for these kind of things.

```
if (isset(whatever))
// this 
else
// other
```

In any case you re-populate input with `post` values:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['the_field']);?>"
```

I mean that you must process all `post` stuff BEFORE output html. For example:

```
if (isset(whatever))
// echo "you posted whatever, great!"
else
// post "value missing, please try again"
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['the_field']);?>"
```

`sessions` are suitable to store permanent data (permanent in a session, of course) To warn `users` about invalid input you must to inform them right after `post` actions. There is no need to save info in `sessions` data.

In conclusion, the normal way to do this is:

```
<?php
if (input data is valid)
    echo 'valid'
else
    echo 'invalid'
?>
<input value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['the_field']); ?>">
```

Comment: where is `isset()` and `echo`?

Comment: Yes it does matter to use `isset()` as you should be checking for the existence of the variable before outputting it since the page can be accessed via GET and the variable will not be available. That's just bad coding.

Comment: @cryptic test `isset` inside an `input` HTMl is not good practice, yes? I only say that is OP wants to see what was `post` 'ed this is the right way. Am  I right or not?

Comment: @cryptic the isset is not a blocker in this case. The issue is somewhere else. Since the op is using isset anyways, I don't see nomikOs's answer to be such a big issue. truth be told I dont think the htmlspecialchars is the problem here. Even if there was some special characterclosing the field early, the op would see some difference in the output. Like some additional text or something

Comment: if OP wants to verify what is available in POST they can do `var_dump($_POST);` to debug, but regardless checking for the existence of $_POST['the_field'] before doing something with it is best practice because that variable will not always exist. I didn't say isset is the OP's issue, but you should not remove it in your answer as you are implying it is not needed.

Comment: @somesh-mukherjee Thanks mate. I think that the question is `that it doesn't retain what I've entered into the fields` Well in this way `input` will be re-populated with the original value posted...

Comment: that is true. but the op did the same thing as you do here minus the isset and the htmlspecialchars. htmlspecialchars will just help prevent a wayward double quote. I think the problem lies in the way the form is handled. if he were validating and populating happen on the same request, this shold work fine. If they are on different requests, this won't work (POST GET Redirect sort of thing)

Comment: @somesh-mukherjee whatever mate and cryptic what about [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qu6Wy20GLNk) Only for veterans! 8)

Comment: @jonthoughtit Yes only works for `self` actions, That is the way that you must to manage `post` data. Only do a redirect to another page (not SELf) after valid/store that data. Well this is only my 2 cents to the cause. good luck.

Comment: @jonthoughtit So what happened. please share!